# WPF TableColumn width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flowdocument

I have a flowdocument where I add a table programmatically. This works fine. But like in word, I want to be able to resize the column size with the mouse. But I can't figure how to do this. 
Is it possible add this feature to a table? 
If its possible, is there an example how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do that.

ContentElements (Tables, Paragraphs, etc.) are not designed to subscribe to any height/width specifications, their content and container determine their size.

But you may play tricks on Margin and Padding binding to go around that. Or there is a similar SO question that may help: [WPF Table Column Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822636/wpf-table-column-sizes)

Comment: Hi KMC, Thanks for your answer and your link.