# WPF FlowDocument Table - change width of columns by mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have to allow a user to change the width of a column and the height of a row for a `Table` in `FlowDocument`.

In my investigation, I've managed to handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for `RichTexBox` control but not for the table border. I suppose I can calculate location of table border but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are more likely to get helpful responses if you post evidence of what you've tried and why it's not working.

Comment: There is no way out of the box. but you can try the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822636/wpf-table-column-sizes